# Is it possible to display one's favorited questions?

Tags: support, feature-request

Is it possible to display one's favorited questions?

I recon not, but it would be useful to have a subtab under the Questions tab that implements this.  By subtab, I mean these sort-tabs: 'newest' 'frequent' 'votes' 'active' 'unanswered'.

Or perhaps implemented as a tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want this tab on your profile:

https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/12820/mike?tab=favorites

That should do what you want.